# Dynamic generation of generics

Tags: c#, generics, amazon-ecs

I have this:

```
Dictionary<Type, List<AbstractThing>> Things { get; set; } = 
    new Dictionary<Type, List<AbstractThing>();
```

I have a large number of concrete AbstractThing classes. As is, the above Dictionary relies on virtual dispatch to function, and that adds unnecessary overhead.

I want to have this instead:

```
Dictionary <Type, List<T>> Things, { get; set; } = new Dictionary<Type, List<T>>();
```

And for the Lists, I want each value to have a different generic. It avoids the overhead of virtual dispatch. Unsure of how to explain this, though.

```
Key-value pair #1 would be: typeof(ConcreteThing1), List<ConcreteThing1>()
Key-value pair #2 would be: typeof(ConcreteThing2), List<ConcreteThing2)()
Key-value pair #3 would be: typeof(ConcreteThing3), List<ConcreteThing3)()

And so on.
```

Is this possible? What is the most write-once-run-anywhere (portable) manner of doing this? For example, a way of embedding a solution into the program  itself (which is portable) would be superior to a code generation tool in an IDE like Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Thats not going to work. How would it know `ConcreteThing1` is a `ConcreteThing2`? The old adage usually fits - if you dont know your type at compile time, you're (probably) using generics wrong.

Comment: Also - I cant see how the code at the top of your question would ever work. http://rextester.com/JIQZX50776

Comment: *As is, the above Dictionary relies on virtual dispatch to function, and that adds unnecessary overhead.* And have you profiled your application and identified virtual dispatch as a major bottleneck in your application? If not, don't even waste your time on it. You are trying to make something very simple, very complicated to shave, at best, a few ms in a section of code that probably isn't running most of the time because some other section of your code is slowing it down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying it's a necessarily a good idea, but you certainly can dynamically generate a generic class, even a collection with something like this:

```
var gt = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
var list = Activator.CreateInstance(gt);
```

Now `list` is a `List<string>`

However, the overhead in doing that might be more than the overhead you are complaining about with virtual dispatch. So unless you have profiled your application and really identified virtual dispatch as being a major bottleneck for your application, I wouldn't even worry about it.

Comment: While absolutely correct at being able to `MakeGenericType` I still dont think this will solve the OP's issue. You cant have different `T` in the same dictionary without deriving from a base class (eg: http://rextester.com/LUYL75126) and using an interface with an `out` type -  which is back to square one for the OP, but worse.

Comment: What about dynamic runtime code generation? Possible?